# Configure windows service through command line

Tags: windows, command-line, service

I need to enable the **"Allow service to interact with desktop"** option in the *service properties* through command line.
How to accomplish that?
I tried the **"sc"** command. But I can't achieve what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried "sc config servicename type= interact type= own"

Also: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/3311c5b7-be80-466e-8d49-fc431115aea9/

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that this feature is pretty much going away in newer versions of windows, for example in Vista it is ignored - services are no longer allowed to interact with the desktop for security reasons