# Enable SqlServer Browser and TCP/IP

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there any way to enable SqlServer Browser Service via command line in C# ? and also the TCP/IP Protocol for SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: net start nameofservice?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839980

Comment: @rene the service is desabled when you install SqlServerExpress, you should enable it and then start it

Comment: @aEkBKF so enable it and start it then. Find out how to enable a service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Configure windows service through command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708875/configure-windows-service-through-command-line)